# Condicionales con fechas dentro de un foreach?

Tags: php, date, foreach, chart.js

Buenas tengo el siguiente código.

```
foreach ($tickets->list as $key => $val) :

 
    $data_fecha =   date("Y-m-d",strtotime($val->data['fec_Emision']['valor'])); 

    if($data_fecha == $data_fecha){
        echo "se repite";
    }
    print_r("<pre>");
    print_r($data_fecha);
    print_r("</pre>");

 endforeach;
```

La salida es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Claro que llega hasta la fecha actual de hoy que es 17.

**Y bueno lo que quiero lograr es que cada vez que se repita la fecha, quiero que las demás se eliminen y solo quede una fecha por cada consulta que se hace**

La consulta que hago es simple y es la siguente:

```
SELECT *  FROM  ticket  WHERE `fec_Emision` >= '2022-10-00' AND `fec_Emision` <= '2022-11-00'ORDER BY `fec_Emision` ASC
```

Y bueno lo que quiero al final de todo esto es que en mi grafico de bar de ChartJs me muestre día por día como en el siguiente gráfico.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la salida que tengo actualmente es esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¡AYUDA!

Comment: *lo que quiero lograr es que cada vez que se repita la fecha, quiero que las demás se eliminen y solo quede una fecha por cada consulta que se hace*, pues ¿por qué no discriminas en la misma consulta SQL con un `GROUP BY`? Así evitarás trasportar datos innecesarios para luego desecharlos.

Comment: ¿Que esperas conseguir con este este condicional?  `if($data_fecha == $data_fecha)` ... siempre se va a cumplir, ¿no crees?

Comment: No se comprende bien tu problema, agrega mas contexto editando tu pregunta. Entendiendo un poco si lo que requieres es traer solo una fecha de tu tabla que tiene la misma repetida N veces, puedes utilizar la declaración **DISTINCT** en tu consulta y solo traerá un resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo entender lo que necesitas, aunque el planteamiento de tu consulta resulta muy confuso.

Entiendo que si haces esa consulta que tienes es porque la usas para otras cosas, no tan solo sacar la fecha, y quieres aprovecharla para conseguir las fechas sin repeticiones.

Si es así, te recomiendo algo así:

```
$fechas_sin_repeticion = [];
foreach ($tickets->list as $key => $val) {
    $fecha_en_el_ciclo = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($val->data['fec_Emision']['valor']));
    if (!in_array($fecha_en_el_ciclo, $fechas_sin_repeticion)) {
         $fechas_sin_repeticion[] = $fecha_en_el_ciclo;
    }
}
print_r($fechas_sin_repeticion);
```

Eso debería mostrarte un array que contiene todas las fechas sin repetir ninguna.

Con eso ahora puedes montarte otros bucles recorriendo `$fechas_sin_repeticion` o lo que necesites para sacar otros datos para tus gráficas.

Si no has entendido algo o mi respuesta no tiene nada que ver con lo que pretendes coméntamelo, gracias.

Comment: @masteguru Gracias es exactamente lo que necesitaba!!